# Manually installing a Kernel/Init System

Tags: linux, openrc

I would like to create a lightweight Linux distribution for my [Raspberry Pi 400](https://www.raspberrypi.com/products/raspberry-pi-400/) (for educational purposes). I have looked at [Buildroot](https://buildroot.org) and [Gentoo Linux](https://www.gentoo.org/), but both require compiling OS components from scratch.

How should I go about building a ROOTFS? I don't have much experience with bare-metal Linux...

Ideally, I would:

- Install the Kernel/[Firmware](https://github.com/raspberrypi/firmware)
- Unpack the [Init System](https://github.com/OpenRC/openrc)
- Get a [Package Manager](https://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/Alpine_Package_Keeper)
- Configure the system

**Related:** [How to easily build your own Linux Distro?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/87011/how-to-easily-build-your-own-linux-distro)

Comment: OK, what's the question? Also why? Start thinking about dependencies and maintenance from the get go. These are very non-trivial and critical things.

Comment: But your 4 steps, that's literally what any Linux distro does (not in that order, usually, but it's the exact same steps)… what's the point? Your distro with an init system, and a package manager, will not be slimmer than a debian or an alpine Linux. Also, your RPi 400 doesn't *call* for anything slimmer – quite the opposite, that's just a desktop or laptop computer in a strange case, and probably serves quite similar use cases, so it'd be quite sensible to *have* a relatively rich environment on there.

Comment: I'd suggest taking a look at DietPi(https://dietpi.com). I've got that running on 2 RasPi B:s now. Unless, of course, the point of the exercise is to learn how to create a Linux distro :-)

Comment: @MarcusMüller To my knowledge, Alpine Linux doesn't run on Raspberry Pi. In the past, I tried using an image from their [Downloads Page](https://alpinelinux.org/downloads/), but I only got a Rainbow Screen

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov I updated the question: I want to see what's inside a distribution like Alpine Linux by installing the Init System and kernel manually

Comment: @GooseDeveloper I'm a bit confused: you can't get a popular distro to run on currently unsupported hardware, but expect to be able to do it all from scratch?

Comment: @GooseDeveloper "seeing what's inside" isn't seen by doing that…

Comment: You could start with LFS.

Comment: @MarcusMüller From components; not from scratch

Comment: So, yeah, that's what a distro installer does. You can just read through the documentation of that one of your choice. But it really boils down to: Partition and format the storage medium, install a basic system from packages into that storage, install a bootloader, reboot.